# What am I doing wrong with this JS array?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following code snippet for my Discord bot.  The first part works and outputs the URL to the console so I know what the output is.  I believe the issue is with my array and if statement.  Am I either not settup the array up correctly or checking of the array includes correct?

My test is that I have an empty Discord server and a test account with no profile pic.  I join that server and the out put to the console is the URL with the 4 down there so I know it's included in the list and matches it exactly.  The problem is that the ban never happens and no errors are thrown so I'm not sure if the includes part is throwing it off or not.  Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have a feeling that it's checking to see if all of the URLs in the array are there and that I need to change the code to check if any of them are in there but I might be wrong.

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
 console.log(member.user.defaultAvatarURL)
});


client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
 const defaultURLs = ["https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png",
  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/2.png",
  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/3.png",
  "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png"]
 if (member.user.defaultAvatarURL.includes(defaultURLs)) {
        member.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'No Profile Pic' })
    }
});
```

Comment: It should have been if (defaultURLs.includes(member.user.defaultAvatarURL)) {
        member.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'No Profile Pic' })
    }

Comment: You shouldn't have more than 1 of each event, this could lead to issues such as memory leaks.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Thanks, let me try that out!

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi That didn't work unfortunately, no change.

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the error you are facing? Can you give the else condition and check , if it is not going to else part .

Comment: There's no error, I'm just able to join the server with an account that has an avatar url of https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png and it doesn't get banned.  Here's my console output: https://prnt.sc/sr53y9

Comment: I don't think I need an else condition because if it doesn't meet the criteria then it can just move on.

Comment: I just wanted to check the flow , it is ok you can remove later on. 
I am trying the same thing , but everything seems to be fine . I pasted the image of console in my answer. Please check that.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I see what you're saying, yeah let me add that in to do a check.  Will keep you posted, really appreciate the help!

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Unfortunately it did not print it out.  I'm gonna give myself a bit of a break from looking at it for now and will come back to it later.

Answer (score 0):

Answering about the includes method. It should have been other way around. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    const defaultURLs = ["https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/1.png",
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/2.png",
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/3.png",
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/4.png"]
     if (defaultURLs.includes(member.user.defaultAvatarURL)) { 
    member.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'No Profile Pic' }) }

});
```

[image: Please see image for clarifications]